# using vxml transfer between 2 extensions

Tags: vxml, voicexml

I want to transfer call from A to extension B. B extension is running vxml as well.

How can I transfer parameters from A to B.

I saw that there is option to append ani parameter to destination. How can i invoke it on B extension vxml?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of any way to pass parameters directly during a transfer in VoiceXML. But you could develop a type of CTI middleware where you store the parameters in a database and key off of a unique number.  You would then use that number as the ANI when you transfer the call, assuming the platform you are using allows you to spoof ANI.  Then when vxml application B answers the call it will first retrieve the ANI and then do a look-up in the database on the ANI to retrieve the parameters.

Comment: It was actually one of the primary options I was looking at, but I don't find how can I retrieve ani number. Any directions there? thanks!

Comment: That is often platform specific. It is probably in the Session Variable [http://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml20/#dml5.1.4]. For example, in the Voxeo Prophecy platform you would look at session.callerid which is not in the VoiceXML specification. You will have to look at your vendor specific documentation to figure that out. What platform are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VXML

Did you try using **aai** attribute of **transfer** tag?

> 

```
 `<transfer
     aai = "string"
     aaiexpr = "ECMAScript_Expression"
   bridgeexpr = "ECMAScript_Expression"
    cond = "string"
    connecttimeout = "integer"
    connecttimeoutexpr = "ECMAScript_Expression"
    dest = "string"
    destexpr = "ECMAScript_Expression"
    expr = "ECMAScript_Expression"
    maxtime = "integer"
    maxtimeexpr = "ECMAScript_Expression"
    name = "string"
    transferaudio = "URI"
    transferaudioexpr = "ECMAScript_Expression"
    type = "string"
    />`
```

string that is sent here can be retrieved as a session parameter in the VoiceXML context
Like this **session.connection.aai**

Hope this helps

Comment: The VoiceXML 2.0 specification states, "Although all platforms must support the aai attribute, platforms are not required to send aai data and need not support receipt of aai data." It is not supported on the Voxeo platform which is what the person asking the question is using. It is too specific to the underling network being used on how this would be transmitted and received and therefore not very portable.

Comment: @KevinJunghans: Hi Kevin , Yeah makes sense, i just saw the discussion between you and **eddyuk**. I understand your point now.